# GridLayout matches parent by resizing the last column and row only (AndroidStudio)

Tags: android, android-studio, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I have a `GridLayout` of 4 columns and 5 rows. If set to `wrap_content` for `layout_width` and `layout_height`, all cells are of equal size, as they should be. When I set it to `match_parent`, however, all cells except those in the last row and column stay the same size, with the last row increasing dramatically in height to fill the rest of the vertical space and the last column increasing in width to fill the rest of the horizontal space. That is, most cells don't resize at all, and row 5 and column 4 become hugely distorted.

`wrap_content`: 
[image]

`match_parent`: 
[image]

How can I have GridLayout keep all cells the same size when it matches parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have static number of rows and columns, you can override cell view's method `onMeasure` this way (if you want to fill, for example, whole display):

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
  int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / COLUMN_COUNT;
  int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / ROW_COUNT;
  setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set all cells to column_weight=x, where x is the same value (1)